# Display decimal numbers (up to 2) with rounding in Javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total = $('#txtBalanceDebito');
    ComputeCosts();

    total.blur(function () {
        ComputeCosts();
    });
});

function ComputeCosts() {
    var amount1 = parseFloat($('#txtDebito').val());
    var amount2 = parseFloat($('#txtBalDisponible').val());


    var total = Math.floor(amount2 - amount1) * (100 / 100);

    $('#txtBalanceDebito').val(total);
}
```

In my ASP page. I need to round up the numbers to display the correct data and not, say, 1.0145641544 like it does. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to round of

```
 var total = total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I had tried that but in the process itself. Darn. Hahaha, thanks.